# Why was my question asking about "how Android works" closed as "too broad"?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, specific-question

today i posted an question regarding [android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/49867/how-does-android-os-works)  os process, this question was closed as

too broad to explain,My question covers the basic os working process?does cananonical questions are not welcome on this community?
i would like to mention all the sites which accepts this kind of questions and explain it for future references for e.g see this [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-work).

Kindly clarify,why my question is closed,i agree that question is too broad to explain,but its an common question which will explain the android os functionality

Comment: If you really want to learn how operating systems work I recommend reading "Modern Operating Systems" by Tanenbaum or for something much lighter try http://computer.howstuffworks.com/operating-system8.htm

Answer (score 6):

Usually questions that could fill a whole book as answer are closed as "too broad" on all sites within the SX network. I can't comment on why this hasn't happened on the Security SX example question you gave. The have the same [policy](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) about "too broad" as any other site. But as eldarathis pointed out, the two questions are not on the same level regarding broadness.

QA sites like Android Enthusiasts work best if you have a specific problem. And no, wanting to know how Android works is not a specific problem.

Comment: see this question http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2885/what-is-the-difference-between-rooting-jailbreak-rom-mod-etc is this problem specific?i can illustrate several questions over here like this,i dont think my question's answer would answer as long as book,to clarify basic info my question would help,i can say many e.g's for long answers with good explanation

Comment: @Lonelybaby: I really disagree that the examples you're citing to support your argument are even on the same level as the question you posted. The Security question, certainly, is *significantly* narrower in scope. You could reasonably summarize how SSL functions in a few sentences if you wanted to (it's a well-defined procedure). Similarly, the question in your above comment is broader than most, but the components are easily explainable **and** extremely common questions. The answer is long because it covers numerous common terms, not because each term requires an essay to describe...

Comment: ...However, "How does Android work?" is so broad that it's practically *meaningless*. How does **what** work? How is memory managed? How is threading handled? How does the OS layer interact with the hardware? How is the UI rendered? Trying to cover the functionality of the entire OS is asking us to explain, literally, *millions of lines of code* in one post. Not only CAN you write an entire book about operating systems and their design, but such books have already been written and they are **hundreds** of pages long.